# Importance value (with varImp from carret package) for one of the two numerical predictors has value 100, how do I interpret this?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

I'm using two numerical predictors to find an outcome, when using varImp (from the carret package) one of the predictors has 100 importance and the other 0.

How should I interpret this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the [caret website](https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html) for how the variable importance is calculated for different models.

100 is the variable with the most importance and 0 the one with the least. By default varImp from caret scales it to have min at 0, max at 100. For example:

```
library(caret)
mdl_glm = train(mpg ~.,data=mtcars,
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=3),method="glm")
```

If we set scale=FALSE, we see the variable importance, in this case it's the absolute t-statistic:

```
VI = varImp(mdl_glm,scale=FALSE)
VI
glm variable importance

     Overall
wt    1.9612
am    1.2254
qsec  1.1234
hp    0.9868
disp  0.7468
drat  0.4813
gear  0.4389
carb  0.2406
vs    0.1510
cyl   0.1066
```

And if we scale it to the maximim:

```
scaledVI = (VI$importance-min(VI$importance))/(max(VI$importance)-min(VI$importance))
100*scaledVI[order(-scaledVI[,1]),drop=FALSE,]
        Overall
wt   100.000000
am    60.325396
qsec  54.825933
hp    47.461739
disp  34.516160
drat  20.202448
gear  17.916750
carb   7.224752
vs     2.391537
cyl    0.000000
```

It's the same as:

```
varImp(mdl_glm)
glm variable importance

     Overall
wt   100.000
am    60.325
qsec  54.826
hp    47.462
disp  34.516
drat  20.202
gear  17.917
carb   7.225
vs     2.392
cyl    0.000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very elaborate answer, It's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: you're welcome :) glad it's useful